# JFrame Components To Update Help (Java)

Tags: java, components, jframe

Alright. So I have a `JFrame`, and it has a `JLabel`. I call the `JFrame`, and it displays properly (with the label). So now I want to call an updater to "update" the `JFrame` to add more buttons and crap. How can I do this WITHOUT having to open up a new `JFrame`?

Comment: update() or repaint() doesn't work? What did you try, what code you used?

Comment: You should add components to a JPanel that uses a layout manager that will behave correctly when adding your new component. Then call revalidate and repaint on the JPanel that receives the new components.

Comment: pack();       [... Just filling character requirement]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `JFrame.invalidate()` first, then call `JFrame.validate().`

```
public void invalidate()
```

Invalidates the container. The container and all parents above it are marked as needing to be laid out.

Comment: When using Swing see Hovercrafts comment to use the revalidate() method. You would use invalidate(), validate() when using AWT.